# Easily run single Windows program?

Tags: software-installation

The calculator program, DreamCalc 4, only runs on Windows. Is there download or a way to run this one program without doubling up on the operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices if there are no Linux-based versions of that program available:

- Setup WINE(Wine Is Not an Emulator)
- Run a virtual machine on your Ubuntu-Host

WINE: https://www.winehq.org/

But I recommend you to use a virtual machine instead of wine, because with wine you are limited concerning the programs.

A tutorial for setting up WINXP as a virtual machine on Ubuntu:
http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Windows-XP-on-Ubuntu-with-VirtualBox

I hope this helps :-)

Comment: Please include instructions in your answer. Unlike forums, Q&A sites like AskUbuntu require that you don't just link to external sources. Include links for reference and further understanding, but at least copy and paste the instructions here.

Answer (score 1):

This program seems to work perfectly with `wine` when installed via `PlayOnLinux`, which is a user-friendly frontend to `wine`.  You can install `PlayOnLinux` from the software center, or by `sudo apt-get install playonlinux`.

Once it's installed, run `PlayOnLinux` from the Dash/Menu.  Once you get to its main screen select `Install`, then click on `Install a non-listed program` at bottom left.  Then, follow the prompts; an installation location will automatically be created.

In my test install of Dreamcalc, I just accepted the suggested defaults (no fancy configuration needed) and named the virtual location "Dreamcalc".

After the install process, you can run Dreamcalc from within `PlayOnLinux` or from your Dash/Menu as with any other (native) program.